Exception when creating user in sandbox: "Invalid Email Address: Must be in domain(s) yourcompany.com"
When trying to create users in one of our test sandboxes, we are getting the following error/exception:
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: 
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Invalid Email Address: Must be in domain(s) yourcompany.com: [Email]

The error appears when trying to create users via Setup area, and also when running test classes.
We have checked already that the following checkbox is OFF:
Setup -> User Management Settings -> Email Domain Allowlist

Are there any ideas/assumptions what else can cause such behaviour in the org?
The error message perfectly matches "Email Domain Allowlist" feature, but again it is OFF. We've already tried enabling it, and then disabling back (just in case), but nothing helps - still same error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Before deactivating, have you tried deleting the allowed email domains in Setup > Allowed Email Domains? If still occurs, contact SF Support. I just tried to replicate your issue at it is fine for me

@compski Allowed Email Domains is empty when we enable it back, so there is nothing to delete. I cannot understand even, how does it know this email domain yourcompany.com, i.e. where it comes from.

@identigral That's what is enabled via "Setup -> User Management Settings -> Email Domain Allowlist", but as mentioned it is turned off in mentioned sandbox altogether.

@wesaw Right, yes. Open a case with Support.

SF support has confirmed that there is one more setting similar to Email Domain Allowlist, but available only from the backend (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385309&type=1) - that what was configured for our sandbox causing such email validation error on user creation.
Extract from the link (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385107&type=1):
The backend 'Allowed Domains List' will override any domain configurations defined by the Restrict User Email Domains page in Setup.
The backend 'Allowed Domains List' can only be viewed and modified by Salesforce Support. 
At this time, there is no way to view the list within your Organization.

